# php parse xml use exactly attribute

Tags: php, xml

**Input `XML`:**

```
 $url = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
<emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="jo"><img>jo_1.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="jo"><img>jo_2.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$imgstring ='';
foreach ($xml->emp_detail->emp as $node ) {     
    if (strpos((string) $node->attributes()->emp_name, "jo") !== false) {
        $imgstring .= (string) $node->img . "<br />";
    }
}
echo ($imgstring);
```

**Current result:**

```
john_1.jpg
john_2.jpg
john_3.jpg
jo_1.jpg
jo_2.jpg
```

But i want get only img with attribute is "jo" like,

**Expected:**

```
jo_1.jpg
jo_2.jpg
```

How to do it?

Comment: Match on `"jo_"` instead, since _all_ files starts with `"jo"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing one thing wrong here `strpos` is to check position of `substring` and `jo` is also a substring of `john` that's why you are getting all the values Instead you can simple use `==` for comparison.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/845488)

**Change this to:**

```
if (strpos((string) $node->attributes()->emp_name, "jo") !== false) {
```

**This:**

```
if ($node->attributes()->emp_name== "jo") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use comparison

```
if ( $node->attributes()->emp_name == "jo" )
```

strpos() returns position of substring and that gets you an integer and integer isn't equal to false. strpos() returns false only if doesn't find the substring in the string (emp_name="david" in youre case).

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath. It allows you to use expressions to select parts of a DOM.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->xpath('/all_emp/emp_detail/emp[@emp_name="jo"]') as $emp) {
  //...
}
```